# Is TScreen thread-safe in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is `TScreen` thread-safe in Delphi 7?

`TScreen` is derived from `TComponent`, that is why I wonder.

Comment: No it's not threadsafe. Of course, threadsafe is a non-specific term. Google for Eric Lippert's article: what is this thing you call thread safe?

Comment: Can I use TScreen in a Thread.execute method ?

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. How would you sync with main thread? What do you want to do? Read screen size. Or access TForm variables.

Comment: I'd use the readonly parts, such as desktop size, but not the methods that cause some kind of change. In particular I'd only run methods that interact with your forms on the main thread.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: even read only stuff can cause problems if they rely on the message queue to retrieve them. Not so much race conditions perhaps, but dead locks definitely need considering.

Comment: You might be alright with screen size code. But it's easy enough to call the Windows API to get that information if you can't convince yourself of the thread safety.

Comment: @Marjan Not really. Message queue not used by any TScreen code. Also queue is per thread. And all message APIs are threadsafe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, true for TScreen. My comment was more directed at the "read only is safe" when using the VCL in general. Message API's are threadsafe, but not "lock-safe". We have experienced hard to trace dead locks because some property getter relied on the message queue. Can't recall the exact details of the top of my head. Do know it took us almost two days to pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: If all you want is screen size, get it from your main thread and pass it through to your other threads when they're kicked off.  Set up your own read/write lock variable that's written from the main thread and read by other threads if you need to handle the screen size changing during thead execution...

Comment: +1 to what Ian Yates says. That'll do the job nicely.

Answer (score 1):

As always, whether something is thread-safe depends on the specific things you want to do. Merely checking a class's ancestry is not sufficient for making a judgment.

Reading the `Height` and `Width` properties of a `TScreen` object will be safe to do from any thread at any time because those property accessors do nothing but call the `GetSystemMetrics` API function. They don't access any data members of the object. You can see for yourself in *Forms.pas*.